# Play before a base score: deciding the order

Tags: smash-up

I can read in the manual that the active player plays first whenever there's a decision about who first resolves an action.

But in this case, what if many players have MULTIPLE cards that can be played? That is with the description 'play before a base scores'

Would each player have to play all the cards he wishes to play? Or could he play one, wait for others to decide what to play and then play the next?

It happened to me with I think the Cthulu faction, there's a minion that lets you draw a madness card for extra power; if you have played several it makes a huge diference since waiting for other players is what decides how many madness cards you'd get

Comment: The [rules for the Cthulhu set](http://www.alderac.com/smashup/files/2013/05/SU3-Rulebook.pdf) explain this under Me First!(page 7). Players play in turn order, starting with the current players turn. When all players pass, resolve the base scoring. If someone didn't pass, you can always choose to play another card. (Note: if the card in question is Cthulhu's Chosen, it can only draw a single Madness card to increase its power from 3 to 5.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the rule book : http://www.alderac.com/smashup/files/2012/06/AEG-SU-Rulebook.pdf

Page 6

> Me First! If more than one player wants to use a Special  ability,
>   start with the current player and go  around the table clockwise until
>   all players pass in  sequence (if you pass and another player uses a 
>   Special, you can then still choose to use a Special  of your own). If
>   your Special allows you to play  extra cards, you must play those
>   immediately or  not at all.

So each player may play one card until everyone is done.